# url rewriting with antlr

Tags: java, antlr

My java program needs to rewrite urls in html (just in time). I am looking for the right tool and wonder if antlr is doing the job for me?

For example:

```
<html><body>  <img src="foo.jpg" /> </body></html>
```

should be rewritten as:

```
<html><body>  <img src="http://foo.com/foo.jpg" /> </body></html>
```

I want to read/write from/to a stream (byte by byte).

Comment: Could you provide a couple of examples that reflect some real cases you want to handle?

Comment: Yes - of course:

<html><body>
  <img src="foo.jpg" />
</body></html>

should be rewritten to:

<html><body>
  <img src="http://foo.com/foo.jpg" />
</body></html>

I want to read/write from/to a stream (byte by byte) ...

Comment: So you're parsing an entire html file (as a stream). AFAIK, ANTLR can handle streams just fine, but writing a full html parser yourself is no trivial task, and I can't imagine there's no tool already out there that doe this. So, I'd ask people here if they know of such a tool instead of asking to help you create such a thing with ANTLR (or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As khmarbaise said, first make sure, if regular expressions can do it. But there are cases, in which they can't [*], and then I think, ANTLR might really be a legitimate choice.

[*] For the mathematical background on this, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_Chomsky_hierarchy

**Update**

Now that you updated your question, I see what you really want to do: For modifying a complete HTML file, I'd use a parser like NekoHTML, or something similar: http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/

Then you can use these to extract the URL. Then

- parse only the URL itself - e. g. with Regexes, Java's URL class (or sometimes better: URI), or maybe ANTLR
- modify the parsed URL
- and write out the HTML again, using NekoHTML/...

Do **not** use regular expressions to parse the entire HTML file! You could use ANTLR for that in theory, but it would be very hard to make that work reliably.

Comment: What has ANTLR to do with regular expressions?

Comment: @Bart: Regexes can parse Chomsky type 3 grammars. ANTLR can additionally parse Chomsky type 2 (context free). It can kick in, where regexes aren't powerful enough anymore. So if you need to do something very complex to the URL - and that's the way I had (mis-?)understood the original version of the question - it could be necessary. Also, even if you use ANTLR to just parse regular languages, it can be a lot cleaner than regexes, because the notation is BNF-like. Using ANTLR requires much more overhead of course, but to replace very complex regexes, it's absolutely worth to consider it!

Comment: @Bart: Of course, after the update of the question (seeing that the author just wants to prepend foo.jpg with something), probably ANTLR won't be necessary... :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about Regular expressions ?